# C#-HatchBrush-"large" checker board hatch style not large enough

Tags: c#, user-controls, drawing, hatchstyle

I'm trying to draw something like the **transparent-indicating background when you use Photoshop** or other image processing software.
Like I said in the title, I'm using HatchBrush, and the large checker board style is not large enough for me. Beyond that, I would rather like to be able to control how large each tile is based on current zoom factor or other stuff in my environment.

I have also written the code to draw a lot of filled rectangles, but this was way too slow for some reason (this allows me to control tile size though).

I have not tried Texture Brush yet, but to have a texture means I can not change the colors on the fly easily, so I would rather avoid that unless run out of options.

Is there any ways that I can configure HatchBrush or do something more basic but efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer when looking at WPF. A solution was on their tutorial with brushes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904%28v=vs.110%29.aspx